# Java ARC on the top of delphi - Invoke error: method 'xxx' not found

Tags: java, android, delphi, exoplayer

Under android and delphi tokyo (so only one single UI thread) I create one  OnFrameAvailableListener and assigne it to a surfaceTexture in this way :

```
  TALFrameAvailableListener = class(TJavaLocal, JSurfaceTexture_OnFrameAvailableListener)
  private
    [Weak] FVideoPlayerControl: TALAndroidVideoPlayer;
  public
    constructor Create(const aVideoPlayerControl: TALAndroidVideoPlayer);
    procedure onFrameAvailable(surfaceTexture: JSurfaceTexture); cdecl;
  end;

  fSimpleExoPlayer := TJExoPlayerFactory.JavaClass.newSimpleInstance(....);                                                                                         
  fSurfaceTexture := TJSurfaceTexture.JavaClass.init(.....);
  FOnFrameAvailableListener := TALFrameAvailableListener.Create(Self);
  fSurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(FOnFrameAvailableListener, TJHandler.JavaClass.init(TJLooper.javaclass.getMainLooper()));
  fSurface := TJSurface.JavaClass.init(fSurfaceTexture);
  fSimpleExoPlayer.setVideoSurface(fSurface);
```

After when i have done with everything I destroy it in this way :

```
  fSimpleExoPlayer.stop;
  fSimpleExoPlayer.clearVideoSurface;
  fSimpleExoPlayer.release;
  fSimpleExoPlayer := nil;

  fSurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(nil);
  fSurface.release;
  fSurface := nil;
  fSurfaceTexture.release;
  fSurfaceTexture := nil;

  freeAndNil(FOnFrameAvailableListener);
```

the problem is that **AFTER** i destroy everything, very rarely, i receive this error :

```
02-01 22:14:28.525: E/Error(12933): Invoke error: method 'onFrameAvailable' not found
02-01 22:14:28.525: E/Error(12933): At address: $8AA6382B (Androidapi.Jnibridge.dispatchToNative(JNINativeInterface**, Androidapi.Jni._JNIObject*, Androidapi.Jni._JNIObject*, Androidapi.Jni._JNIObject*, Int64) + 902)
```

So something in Java is still trying to call OnFrameAvailableListener even **after** i release everything :( I think under Java with it's own ARC where we never really free any objects this is not really a problem and OnFrameAvailableListener will be still available even after we release everything, but under delphi, even if i don't do freeAndNil(FOnFrameAvailableListener); the compiler will deccrease it's refcount to 0 and thus freeing it :(

So how can i do ?

Comment: `FreeAndNil` on ARC compiler? For what purpose? Just use `FOnFrameAvailableListener := nil;` Anyway, sounds like a threading issue... callback is most likely called from different thread...

Comment: yes FreeAndNil on ARC compiler :) yes here it's will be the same as FOnFrameAvailableListener := nil; but i take habit to always call FreeAndNil  (because often the code you write is not only for ARC but also for win32/win64). Ah yes i forget to say, callback is call ONLY in the mainthread (this because i gave TJHandler.JavaClass.init(TJLooper.javaclass.getMainLooper() to fSurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener

Comment: If callback is on synchronized with main thread then there is your problem. your code will execute before final callback is called. You would have to delay releasing the callback itself and give chance to callback call to synchronize with the main thread before you finally release the callback. There may be other state listeners that may be appropriate to attach to and release callback from them - after your player is finally released.

Comment: Oh, and there is another possible solution. Calling fSurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(nil); before you begin destroying anything else.

Comment: @Dalija hmmmm very interesting idea ! i will try it tonight (because i must leave the app working all the night to reproduce it).

Comment: The last idea depends on what happens during player release. If callback is triggered by any of the methods you call during destruction, then setting listener to nil before you start destruction will help, however if the callback is created before you start destruction process, you will end up having the same problem. It is impossible to tell without looking at the actual player code (not yours) and its inner workings - how it handles callbacks.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: well view, it's was this :)